# Carberry on Linux Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, pi-2, raspbian-stretch

I recently bought a new Carberry (http://www.carberry.it/index.php)  for Raspberry Pi B 2/3, together with its Carbian OS and installed it on a Raspberry Pi3/ModelB.

However, It shuts down few seconds after I connect the Carberry board to the 12V DC power supplier of the Lab Machine. My Carberry is not connected to an OBD port, it is only connected to the +12V red and GND black wires on Carberry connector pins 1 and 2 with the DC power supplier. No other pin is connected.

Did anyone here face the same problem and managed a solution to this problem ?

Comment: According to the specifications, it only supplies 5v at 1 amp. This isn't enough for a RasPi 3.

Comment: According to Carberry spec, Up to more than one ampere at 5 volt, can be drawn from the switching regulator, enough to power a fully loaded Raspebrry Pi." Also, they are using rpi in their projects, so I don't understand why it can't work for me also

Comment: Problem fixed by connecting the blue/yellow wire of ignition input signal to a 12V DC supplier.

Comment: Please write that as an answer and accept it. You will help others by doing this. This may sound silly, but at least I'm not asking you to answer in the form of a question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed by connecting the blue/yellow wire of ignition input signal to a 12V DC supplier.